# How can I change timezone and go back previous timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone, connection, mybatis

My project libary version is
mybatis 3.1
postgresql 9.2

I want to change connection timezone before select query. and back to the timezone.

first, I try it. set timezone in mapper xml.

```
set timezone = 'Asia/Seoul' ;
select now();
set timezone = 'UTC';
```

I think If an error occurs when select query, Timezone is not set to UTC.
If timezone is not set to UTC, Query on the different request will be utc time.

second, I try it. sqlsession injected by spring DI.

```
sqlsession.selectOne(namespace.setTimezone, 'Asia/Seoul');
sqlsession.selectOne(namespace.selectNow);
sqlsession.selectOne(namespace.setTimezone, 'UTC');
```

I think. three sqlsession this may not be the same connection.

How can I change timezone and go back previous timezone?
If I process transactions, three sqlsession happens is the same connection?

Answer (score 1):

Use a transaction.

It mybatis is worth its salt, it will support database transactions, and it has to use the same connection for all statements within one transaction.

I don't know if mybatis can do this, but in PostgreSQL you can use `SET LOCAL` to change a parameter only for the duration of a transaction. It will be reset automatically at the end of the transaction.